# Debug console in visual studio 2019

Tags: windows, debugging, console, visual-studio-2019

I am used to use the Visual Studio for **mac** and the debug console is integrated inside the application. The thing is that in Windows version when you debug, the console pops out which is a bit of annoying.
I wonder if there is any way to have it the same way in Visual Studio for **Windows** as well?

Comment: Hi Ismail, is your issue solved?

Comment: Yes, it is solved now. Could not upvote as I should have at leat 15 reputation to cast a vote.

Comment: It’s ok, you can summarize and post an answer below, then [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, this will benefit other forum members. Have a great day:)

Answer (score 2):

Don’t know what kind of project you are using, it seems you can try to change the Output type of the project, from `Console Application` to `Windows Application`(for debugging, right-click your project > Properties > Application > Output type). (I tested with console application)

And also consider this option: Tools > Options… > Debugging > General > Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window.